# Add Region URL to Geochart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am creating a map using Google Geochart and need a listener so that when the user clicks on a region it loads a given URL.

My code is:

```
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {packages: ['geochart'], callback: drawVisualization});

  function drawVisualization() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Country', 'Value', {role: 'tooltip', p:{html:true}}],
    ['US', 20, '<a href="http://www.ipfa.org/council/branches/39/ipfa-americas/">Test</a>'],
    ['Canada', 20, 'http://www.ipfa.org/council/branches/106/ipfa-canada/'],
    ['GB', 20, 'http://www.ipfa.org/council/branches/52/ipfa-uk/'],
   ]);

   var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    var row = selection[0].row;
    var url = data.getValue(row, 3);
    window.open(url);
   });

    chart.draw(data, {
     width: 800,
     height: 600,
     tooltip: {
      isHtml: true
     }
    }
   );
  }
```

The URL listener works on another map I use, what am I doing wrong to not work on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues.  First, you are using the wrong index to reference your URLs; they are in column 2, not column 3 (which doesn't exist):

```
var url = data.getValue(row, 3);
```

Second, one of your URL's (for the US) is an anchor tag, which won't work if passed to the `window.open` call.  If you want anchor tags in the tooltips, set the value of the cell to the URL and formatted value of the URL column to the anchor tag:

```
['US', 20, {v: 'http://www.ipfa.org/council/branches/39/ipfa-americas/', f: '<a href="http://www.ipfa.org/council/branches/39/ipfa-americas/">Test</a>'}]
```

I would also suggest testing for the length of the selection array, because it is possible for the selection array to be empty if the user clicks a region twice in a row (the second click deselects the region), which would cause this line to throw an error:

```
var row = selection[0].row;
```

I suggest using this instead:

```
var selection = chart.getSelection();
if (selection.length) {
    var url = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 2);
    window.open(url);
}
```